# Wordpress: How to use post_class() in an echo

Tags: array, post-class

I am working on a foreach loop in Wordpress and want to add 'post_class()' to a div within it. Currently the code looks like this:

```
if ( is_array( $posts ) && !empty( $posts ) ) {

    echo '<ul class="tribe-related-events tribe-clearfix hfeed vcalendar">';
    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
        echo '<li>';
            echo '<div class="overlay">';
                echo   '<div '. post_class() .'>'; 
                echo        '<h3>'. tribe_get_event_taxonomy() .'</h3>';
                echo    '</div>';
            echo '</div>';
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

The 'post_class()' function is breaking the div it is in and calling the classes as if they were content in the page.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution has actually been less complicated than I initially thought. The post_class() function does not return a string, but instead it "echoes" the string.
Therefore, when you write.

```
echo '<div ' . post_class() . '>';
```

The effect is the following:

First, the system execute post_class(), generating an "echo ...." with the class attribute
second, the system makes the requested concatenation and echoes the text "".

The right way to use it is:

```
echo "<div ";
post_class();
echo ">";
```

or else:

```
echo '<div class="'. join( ' ', get_post_class() ) .'">';
```

Comment: Thanks for a perfect answer to your own question. I prefer the `join()` method since it makes the markup really obvious.

Comment: It looks like @kaiser got there first with a similar answer and so probably deserves the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

The [`post_class()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.9.1/wp-includes/post-template.php#L369) function just is a wrapper for [`get_post_class()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.9.1/wp-includes/post-template.php#L392).

Keep in mind that the latter does not `echo`, but returns an `Array` so you have to do something like what `post_class()` does:

```
$classes = join( '  ', get_post_class() );
```

Your code (could) would look like the following. I changed the `if` check as well to first check if `$posts` is empty and then check if it is an array - which is more fail safe.

```
if (
    ! empty( $posts )
    AND is_array( $posts )
    )
{
    $items = array();
    foreach ( $posts as $post )
        $items[] = sprintf(
            '<li><div class="overlay"><div class="%s"></div><h3>%s</h3></div></div></li>',
            join( '  ', post_class() ),
            tribe_get_event_taxonomy()
        );

    ! empty( $items ) AND printf(
        '<ul class="tribe-related-events tribe-clearfix hfeed vcalendar">%s</ul>',
        join( '', $items )
    );
}
```